# Node: How to Push Data into Json File... data.push Not Working

Tags: node.js, json, express

I want to push some data into json file and data comes from user i have data.json file

#### My Code:

```
var router = express.Router();
var data = require('./../public/json/data.json')
router.post('/addTask', (req, res) => {
    var last = data[data.length - 1]
    newTask = {
        "id": Number(last.id) + 1,
        "task": req.body.task,
        "date": req.body.date,
        "category": req.body.category,
        "complited": false
    };
    data.push(newTask)
    res.json(data)

})
```

#### data.json:

```
[
{
    "id": "3",
    "task": "Attend a Training",
    "date": "2020-04-20",
    "category": "Office Task",
    "complited": true
},
{
    "id": "4",
    "task": "Prepration of Exam",
    "date": "2020-04-10",
    "category": "Collage Task",
    "complited": true
},
{
    "id": "5",
    "task": "Write Assignments",
    "date": "2020-04-10",
    "category": "Collage Task",
    "complited": true
}
]
```

i checked this in postman in output of postman it works fine it push data and show right data but when i checked my data.json file its not updated whats the reason behind that let me show the Output

#### Postman:

[image: Postman Output]

#### data.json File

[image: data.jsonFile]

i also try :

```
data.push(newTask)
res.json(data)
data=data
```

but its not even working
can someone solve this issue? or have any hint?

Comment: What is in the `data` variable? Can you show us the code that loads the JSON file?

Comment: I update the code please check

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: No even i get perfect result in postman its shows the data with object i push but in actual in data.json shows the actual previous data

Comment: returns with status 200

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to realize that loading a JSON file with `require` doesn't give you a file reference. Instead, Node will read the JSON file and create a JavaScript object from it (likely using something similar to `JSON.parse`).

So the `data` variable in your code is not the actual `data.json` file, but rather a variable which contains the contents of `data.json`. So when you modify `data`, you only modify the data you have in memory, not the file. In order to save the changes to file you need to write the updated data inside of `data` to the file `data.json` again. You can do this using the `fs.writeFile` function like this:

```
fs.writeFile('data.json', JSON.stringify(data), 'utf8', callback);
```

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback

Comment: Hey Thank you for your Response i tried  this and it show me error like callback is not defined then i refer the link you give and from that i change little bit in code and it working I chenged: `fs.writeFile('data.json', JSON.stringify(data), (err) => {
        if (err) throw err
        console.log("Updated...")
    });`

Comment: Great that you solved that yourself! Indeed, I was quick and didn't declare the callback variable in my example. But it would have been something like `const callback = (err) => { if (err) { throw err; } console.log("Updated...") };`. To inline it into the function call is also fine!

Comment: i just forgot to do that Thank you so much for your solution it means a lot and you save my time  :)